# Exporting dataframe of max value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, max

I have 5 CSV file that contains stats of incidents, I am copying the data of these files into separate dataframes, called file1, file2, file3, file4, and file5, I can find the max number of occurrences out of these files with no issue, however, my next target is to stat analyzing the data of the max file (e.g., file1), so I can to export it to a new dataframe and then start playing with it.

```
data = (file1, file2, file3, file4, file5)
max1= np.max(data)
print()
print("Maximum number of incidents are:", max1)
```

How this can be achieved please?

Answer (score 0):

The expected output is unclear, do you want to create a Series/DataFrame like this:

```
data = {'file1': file1, 'file2': file2, 'file3': file3, 'file4': file4, 'file5': file5}

s = pd.Series({f: np.max(d) for k,d in data.items()})
```

For a DataFrame:

```
df = pd DataFrame({'max': s})
```